# Tax filing for Summer Internship

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I have a couple questions regarding the tax filing procedure. I am still a dependent on my parents, and my parents normally do the taxes each year. However, last summer 2014 I worked a summer intern at a hospital. My total income for the internship was $11100. After taxes, I made around $7700 . Basically my question is whether I need to file taxes separately, or can my parents still take care of it. For instance, can my parents still claim me as a dependent? Also, am I eligible for a tax refund? Over the summer, my total federal withholding was around $1600.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to file a tax return.

For a single individual under the age of 65 who is a dependent, the [filing threshold](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p501/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000220698) is $6200 or more of earned income, and your income is above that.

Since your parents claim you as a dependent - you cannot claim an exemption for yourself, but as Joe said,  you'll still have the standard deduction.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend on more details like your age, whether or not you are a student, do you still live at home, etc.

The [IRS has a calculator](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Who-Can-I-Claim-as-a-Dependent%3F) to help determine your status as a dependent.

You will need to file a tax return regardless because your earned income was over the standard deduction amount.

Comment: I am not married and 21 yrs old and a college student in NYC living with my parents.

Comment: If they paid for more than half your support, they can claim you as dependent. Use the calculator to make sure, though. When you file your tax return, I predict a refund.

Comment: Or you could just ask if they are claiming you as a dependent (assuming they are doing it correctly)

Answer (score 1):

As a dependent, you lose your 'exemption' but not your standard deduction. For a single person, that's $6200, leaving $4900 to be taxed at your rate, 10%. I predict a federal tax bill of $490, and you've already paid $1600, so I smell 'refund'.